# What is the surface area of $z=2xy$ bounded by surfaces $x+y=1$, $x=0$ and $y=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, area

> What is the surface area of $z=2xy$ bounded by surfaces $x+y=1$, $x=0$, $y=0$

So far I calculated the partial derivatives $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 2y $ and $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 2x $. My region of integration on $xy$ plane is bounded by $x=0$, $y=0$ and $y=1-x$.

This gives me the following double integral to solve: $$\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^{1-x}\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2}dy\right)dx$$

I would be grateful if someone could help me with solving this integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to polar coordinates, translate and exploit symmetry, then substitute $\sin t = \sqrt3\, \sin s$ to get a manageable integral:

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} \sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2} \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \int_0^{\tfrac1{\sin t+\cos t}} r \sqrt{1+4r^2} \, dr \, dt & (x,y)=(r\cos t,r\sin t) \\
&= -\frac\pi{24} + \frac1{12} \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \left(\frac{5+\sin(2t)}{1+\sin(2t)}\right)^{3/2} \, dt \\
&= -\frac\pi{24} + \frac1{12} \int_{-\tfrac\pi4}^\tfrac\pi4 \left(\frac{5+\cos(2t)}{1+\cos(2t)}\right)^{3/2} \, dt & t\to t-\frac\pi4 \\
&= -\frac\pi{24} + \frac16 \int_0^\tfrac\pi4 \frac{\left(1-\frac13\sin^2t\right)^{3/2}}{\cos^3t} \, dt \\
&= -\frac\pi{24} + \frac32 \int_0^{\operatorname{arccsc}\sqrt6} \frac{\cos^4s}{\left(1-3\sin^2s\right)^2} \, ds
\end{align*}$$

Following up with substituting [$s=2\arctan p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) is standard. It may also help to expand

$$\frac{\left(1-\sin^2s\right)^2}{\left(1-3\sin^2s\right)^2} = \frac19 + \frac{\frac49}{1-3\sin^2s} + \frac{\frac49}{\left(1-3\sin^2s\right)^2}$$

so that

$$\frac1{1-3\sin^2s} = \frac{\left(p^2+1\right)^2}{\left(p^2-\left(5+2\sqrt6\right)\right) \left(p^2 - \left(5-2\sqrt6\right)\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you for these useful tips. Now I managed to calculate it til the end.